# Closure of $(0, 1)$ and Convergence of $\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

I recently learned that in the metric space $(0, 1)$ w.r.t. the usual metric $d$, $(0, 1)$ is closed in $((0, 1), d)$. This means that $\overline{(0, 1)}$ = $(0, 1)$ in $((0, 1), d)$.

Now, if we take the sequence $(\frac{1}{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $(0, 1)$, then it  converges to $0$ w.r.t. $d$. This means $0$ is an accumulation point. Does this necessarily mean $0 \in \overline{(0, 1)}$? $0$ is an accumulation point, so it's in $(0, 1)'$, but I'm not sure if it is in the closure of $(0, 1)$. I don't think it is, since $(0, 1)' \ne \overline{(0, 1)}$, but I'm not sure if that's the correct way to think about it.

If indeed $0 \in \overline{(0, 1)}$ in $((0, 1), d)$, that does not imply $0 \in (0, 1)$, right, the the "union" definition of closure above?

Comment: The sequence $\{\frac{1}{n}\}$ does not converge in the space $(0,1)$, since the point 0 doesn't exist as far as the space $(0,1)$ is concerned.  Think of this as being analogous to the sequence $\{n\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, which diverges to infinity.  Indeed, this shows that $(0,1)$ is not a complete metric space with respect to the usual distance (since the sequence you describe **is** Cauchy, unlike the sequence $\{n\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$).  On the other hand, the closure of $(0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is the closed interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Even though $\{ \frac 1n \}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(0,1)$, it does not have a limit (this shows $((0,1),d)$ is not a complete metric space). In other words: $0$ is in the completion of $(0,1)$, but not the closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, $\overline{(0,1)}$ is the smallest closed set *in $(0,1)$* that contains $(0,1)$, which is $(0,1)$. The point $0$ is not a point in the metric space $\big((0,1),d\big)$. The sequence $(1/n)$ does not converge to anything in this metric space.